# Bad space between li and border

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Why is there a space between `li` elements and `border` in `header`? There should be no space between li elements and border.

Website: [**My Webite**](http://webstranka.4fan.cz/cz/about-us/)

PS: `li` elements have`float:left` and `overflow:auto`

Comment: Merry Christmas!!.....looks fine to me,can you please be a bit more specific, where exactly is the extra `space`...the `grey menu` or `green menu`??

Comment: Plese post a code demostration not your website :\

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to img tag inside li and it will fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much i dont have reputation to thumbs up.

Comment: You are welcome and No problem if you don't have reputation to thumbs up. :)

Answer (score 0):

`margin-right:0.1875%` on `ul#menu li` a is creating space between your li elements. Adjust as required.

Answer (score 0):

Remove overflow:auto ;

Styling for li should be:

```
#pages_redirect ul li  {


height:50px;
}
```